# php app/console doctrine:database:import returns OutOfMemoryException

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to import a postgresql dmp file through doctrine commands. It throws an OutOfMemoryException, despite cleaning the app/cache directory before the import. Any idea on how I could fix this?

```
$ rm -rf app/cache/*

$ ll app/cache
total 0

$ php app/console doctrine:database:import zen_prod_20180625091104.dmp -vvv
Processing file '/home/xxxxxx/Documents/Projets/zen2/zen_prod_20180625091104.dmp'... 
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36864 bytes) in /home/btraband/Documents/Projets/zen2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 1098

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36864 bytes) in /home/btraband/Documents/Projets/zen2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 1098


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException]                     
  Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36864 bytes)                                                                 


Exception trace:
 () at /home/xxxxxx/Documents/Projets/zen2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:1098

doctrine:database:import [--connection [CONNECTION]] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-s|--shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> <file> (<file>)...

$ ll zen_prod_20180625091104.dmp 
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxx xxxxxx 28M 25 juin  09:11 zen_prod_20180625091104.dmp
```

Find some information on my config below:

```
$ php app/console --version
Symfony version 2.8.39 - app/dev/debug

$ composer show | grep -i -e doctrine
doctrine/annotations                 v1.6.0  Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.7.1  Caching library offering an ...
doctrine/collections                 v1.5.0  Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.8.1  Common Library for Doctrine ...
doctrine/dbal                        v2.6.3  Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.6.7   Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       1.3.3   Symfony Bundle for Doctrine ...
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle  v1.3.1  Symfony DoctrineMigrationsBu...
doctrine/inflector                   v1.3.0  Common String Manipulations ...
doctrine/instantiator                1.1.0   A small, lightweight utility...
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1  Base library for a lexer tha...
doctrine/migrations                  v1.2.2  Database Schema migrations u...
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.14 Object-Relational-Mapper for...
gedmo/doctrine-extensions            v2.4.35 Doctrine2 behavioral extensions

$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.9
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to increase memory_limit in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

You can try increassing single command's memory size, for example importing very large database you can use:

```
php -d memory_limit=10240M bin/console doctrine:database:import import.sql
```